# Cannot resolve symbol in android studio from import

Tags: java, android, android-studio, import

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;

Cannot resolve symbol 'Snackbar'-> this is from the import statement

any help? thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like your project is missing a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Snackbar dependency to your app gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Then click **Sync Now**

Comment: I get the following errors: ->  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1' - This support library should not use a different version (27) than the compileSdkVersion (28) and it breaks a default implementation, --> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3' All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0-alpha3, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Braythor because the latest and stable version is 27.1.1, you can change targetSdkVersion 28 down to 27 and resync.

Comment: Ok @sontruongit i'll try that and I'll get back to you.

Comment: It worked but it broke some parts of my project but overall success. Thank you so much. I will mark this as answer.

Comment: Good to hear that, version 28 is in alpha test, so I think you should go with the latest stable version. Happy coding!

Comment: Got it. I think it just set that, i didn't set it personally. Maybe it is just when you target Android Version in create project. I just go with the defaults.